# React.js: How to get all props component expects?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, enzyme, jestjs

I'm starting to unit test a React.js application and one of the challenge I'm facing is to determine all the props a component needs to mount it properly. Is there any utility to check what all is needed to mount the component successfully? Additionally the data type of those props to initialize them appropriately for component rendering.

Like one of my component is getting props from parent using spread `{...props}` operator. And the parent is also getting these using spread operator and then adds some additional props and passes it to child. Which makes it very difficult for me to get all props a components expects. Is there any legit way to get the list of props?

Comment: Maybe the component should be always able to mount properly. Maybe if you provide defaultProps to the component you can save yourself from trouble. In that case there's no question which props are needed to mount properly because component always mounts correctly. The best problem is no problem :-). Hope I helped

Comment: hmm.. but the thing is to be able to set defaultProps I need to know the props the component needs! That is basically the problem.

Comment: This sounds like a great case for a JSDoc (docblock), like explained here: https://github.com/reactjs/react-docgen/issues/98

Answer (score 2):

**An Interesting task.**

I start with:

```
import React from "react";
import * as PropTypes from "prop-types";

function Hello(props) {
  const { boo, foo } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{boo}</h1>
      <h2>{foo}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

Hello.propTypes = {
  boo: PropTypes.string,
  foo: PropTypes.number
};

export default Hello;
```

I found this article https://blog.jim-nielsen.com/2020/proptypes-outside-of-react-in-template-literal-components/ with function:

```
/**
 * Anytime you want to check prop types, wrap in this
 * @param {function} Component
 * @param {Object} propTypes
 * @return {string} result of calling the component
 */
function withPropTypeChecks(Component) {
  return props => {
    if (Component.propTypes) {
      Object.keys(props).forEach(key => {
        PropTypes.checkPropTypes(
          Component.propTypes,
          props,
          key,
          Component.name
        );
      });
    }
    return Component(props);
  };
}
```

Then I wrote another one:

```
const getPropsInfo = (component) => {
  const result = {};
  const mock = Object.keys(component.propTypes).reduce(
    (acc, p) => ({ ...acc, [p]: Symbol() }),
    {}
  );
  const catching = (arg) => {
    const [, , prop, type] = `${arg}`.match(
      /Warning: Failed (.*) type: Invalid .* `(.*)` of type `symbol` supplied to.*, expected `(.*)`./
    );
    result[prop] = type;
  };
  const oldConsoleError = console.error.bind(console.error);
  console.error = (...arg) => catching(arg);
  withPropTypeChecks(component)(mock);
  console.error = oldConsoleError;
  return result;
};
```

I chose Symbol as the less expected type.

And called it:

```
const propsInfo = getPropsInfo(Hello);
console.log(propsInfo);
```

As result I got: `{boo: "string", foo: "number"}`

P.S.: I have not tested this on other types. Just for fun! :)

Answer (score 0):

For [unit testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) this will be totally OK for your parent component to check only that properties which it adds to its child. Because in unit testing you just test functionality of a particular unit. In this case you want to check that your parent component adds all the needed properties to its child and passes all the other properties that it takes (whatever they are).

In parallel you test your child component and check its functionality.

To check that two or more components interact with each other correctly you should use [E2E/functional testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_testing). In this case you will test some functionality parts of your working app. If you have some issues with component interaction they will pop up.

Answer (score -1):

One way to solve this problem will be to use decorators. I understand that they are not yet fully here and as for now you might need to use typescript or such. But it is a solution to the stated problem that will allow you to decorate and attach any required information to the properties of your component. Below is an example in typescript:

```
@PropContainer("Textbox")
export class TextboxProps
{
    @Prop(PropertyType.Mandatory)
    public propA: string;

    @Prop(PropertyType.Optional)
    public propB?: number;
}
```